# Creating a string from column data is not storing full data

Tags: excel, vba, string, transpose

I am writing a macro that reads a list of values form a column in Excel, stores them in a string object and then transfers them to a specific location in a text file. I am having no problems with the transfer part. However, for some reason the string is not storing all the values in the desired column. The column has about 250,000 cells with values. I am guessing it is a size limitation of using string or an issue with my code. I think the source is with how I set the size of the `Nodes` object. The last row that defines the range is `Number_of_Nodes` and if I change it, the output varies accordingly. I have tried with smaller number of data and it works fine. Any suggestions?

```
Dim Number_of_Nodes As Long
Dim Nodes As Range
Dim NodesCell As Range
Dim NodesList As String

'Determine number of nodes
Number_of_Nodes = Workbooks("Dent Input Deck.xlsm").Sheets(".inp").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1

'Store *node list into string variable
Set Nodes = Workbooks("Dent Input Deck.xlsm").Sheets(".inp").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Number_of_Nodes, 1))
'For Each NodesCell In Nodes
    'Debug.Print NodesCell.Value
'Next NodesCell
NodesList = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Nodes.Value), vbNewLine)
Debug.Print NodesList`
```

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Nodes.Value)` has limit of roughly 64,000.  You will need to load them into an array then loop that array and write it to the csv line by line with the line break.

Comment: Ummm, why spend all that effort and dynamic space allocation on an array?  Open a file, loop through the sheet columns and write out what you find there...

Comment: The array works but like Chris mentioned, it is time consuming and over the long term not very efficient. The only issue is that I need that data to be placed at a certain location in the text file using a placeholder or something to identify the location with.